# Sequelize data type for postgresql full text search

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, full-text-search

I've been wrestling to enable full text search through Sequelize (yeah, the project is based on it so far) and have a couple of troubles including, that I couldn't add field in the schema for text tokens.

```
var Article = db.define(
    'article',
{
    ...
    tokens: Sequelize.STRING
}
```

I've tried Sequelize.STRING, Sequelize.TEXT, Sequelize.JSONB, etc with no luck. Fyi, `tokens` field is generated through `to_tsvector` function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally ended up using raw text like following:

```
tokens: { type: 'TSVECTOR' }
```